# Converting a String to an NVarChar in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, code-behind

I've got the following lines of code:

```
 string txtClient = (DT1["CLIENT_ID"].ToString());
 txtClientID.Text = txtClient;
```

Due to a back-end change, I need to actually make this an NVarChar.  Is there a CAST or CONVERT or some other command that will allow me to make this an NVarChar instead of a String?

Comment: In C#, a string is a series of Unicode characters already. If you had to change your code anywhere, it'd be on the database side. Here is a [SQL Server to .NET data mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx). As you can see, nvarchar and varchar both map to string.

Comment: NVarChar is a datatype in the Sql world. The corresponding type in C# is string.

Comment: NVarChar is represent as string in c#! What do you need to do with this value that requires such thing?

Comment: I'm getting an error message that says, "Error converting data type nVarChar to Numeric".  Is that on the SQL end?  If I pass it in as Numeric instead of String, will the work?  If so, how do I convert the above to Numeric?

Comment: @JohnnyBones, in that case the error has nothing to do with your posted code. Your question should have that part of the code where you are passing the values to your query.

Comment: That error message suggests that you already have an NVarChar (somewhere) and that it's failing to convert to a numeric value.

Comment: you are converting nvarchar data to numeric in your c# code